# .attachment issues in vba

Tags: vba, pdf, gmail, attachment

```
   Dim strto As String
   Dim lastrow As Long
   stirfile = Dir(DestPath & "*.pdf*")
   For i = lastrow To 7 Step 1
   lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   strto = Range("G7") & ";" & Range("K7") & ";" & Range("O7") & ";" & Range("S7")
   With Mail
      .Subject = "Quote reg for VAM project"
      .From = "arunkumarg@gmail.com"
      .To = strto
      .CC = ""
      .BCC = ""
      .TextBody = strbody
              .Attachments.Add (DestPath)
   End With
   Next i
   Mail.Send
End Sub
```

i just want to gmail all the pdf files in my destpath & i am failing miserably on ".Attachment" area
kindly guide me

Comment: "fail miserably" is not helpful. What error messages are you getting? Did you single step through the code?

Comment: What is `DestPath`? Maybe you miss just a backslash `Dir(DestPath & "\*.pdf*")`? Impossible to tell.

Comment: DestPath - "P:\kin\PROJECTS\TARSON\Newfolder1\"

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66581781/edit) the question. [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates how to loop through files in a folder with `Dir`.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Private Sub attachFilesInFolder()
    
    Dim myMail As MailItem
    Dim olApp As outlook.Application
    
    Dim DestPath As String
    
    Dim stirFilePath As String
    Dim stirFile As String
    
    DestPath = "P:\kin\PROJECTS\TARSON\Newfolder1\"
    stirFilePath = DestPath & "*.pdf"
    
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "stirFilePath.......: " & stirFilePath
    
    Set olApp = New outlook.Application
    
    Set myMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        
    With myMail
        
        .Subject = "Quote reg for VAM project"
        
        stirFile = dir(stirFilePath)
        Debug.Print "DestPath & stirFile: " & DestPath & stirFile
            
        Do While stirFile <> ""
            Debug.Print "       stirFile....: " & stirFile
            .Attachments.add (DestPath & stirFile)
            stirFile = dir
        Loop
            
    End With
        
    myMail.Display
   
End Sub
```